# where does $i$ (imaginery) go in the equation of magnitude of euler's formula?

Tags: complex-numbers, eulers-number-e

$$\begin{align}
e^{i\theta}&=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta \\[0.5em]
\left|e^{i\theta}\right|&=\sqrt{\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta}
\end{align}$$

I get that the magnitude of $e^{i\theta}$ has to be $1$, but why does that $i$ squared become $1$? Isn't $i$ squared supposed to be $-1$?

Comment: If $z:=x+iy$, where $x$ and $y$ are both real, then $|z|$ is simply *defined* as $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. The $i$ doesn't enter the calculation; it simply serves as a way to distinguish the *real* and *imaginary* components of $z$. ... Alternatively, $|z| = \sqrt{z\overline{z}}$, where $\overline{z}:=x-iy$ is the *conjugate* of $z$. Here, the $i$ *does* enter the calculation, and we get $$z\overline{z}=x^2-(iy)^2=x^2-i^2y^2=x^2-(-1)y^2=x^2+y^2$$ which gives the same result as before.

Answer (score 1):

In the real numbers, $|z| = \sqrt{z^2}$. However, in the complex numbers this is no longer true. Instead, we say that $|z| = \sqrt{z\bar{z}}$ where $\bar{z}$ is the complex conjugate of $z$, with $\overline{x + iy} = x - iy$. Notice that $(x + iy)(x - iy) = x^2 - i^2 y^2 = x^2 + y^2$, which guarantees that $|z|$ is always a non-negative real number. Also, notice that if $z$ is real, then $\bar{z} = z$ so that $|z| = \sqrt{z^2}$ still.

Then if $z = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$, $|z| = \sqrt{(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)(\cos \theta - i \sin \theta)} = \sqrt{\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta} = \sqrt{1} = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Think about a right triangle with height $\sin \theta$ and base $\cos \theta$, the number $\cos\theta + i\sin\theta$ is the tip of the triangle in the complex plane. So to compute the hypothenuse you do the pythagorean theorem which is the formula for $\left|e^{i\theta}\right|$ you mentioned.